# How can I make all-possible-regressions in R also include exponents and logs of the variables?

Tags: r, statistics

I'm using the `olsrr` package for statistical analysis when trying to compare as many model specifications as possible using all-possible-regressions.

My code:

```
model <- lm(y ~ ., data = "mydata"
k <- ols_all_subset(model)
```

which gives me a table with R2, adjusted R2, AIC, SIC etc for each combination of variables *as is* (linear). For example, if the variables are x1, x2 and x3, it gives me a table with R2, AIC, SIC etc for the specifications with every possible linear-linear specifications: with x1 x2 and x3 as regressors, with x1 and x2, with x1 and x3, with x2 and x3, and each of just x1, just x2, and just x3.

However, I also want to get all possibles for squares and logs of the variables to look at every possible major specification, for instance x1^2, log(x1), log(x3) etc.

I know I could individually create a new column and generate each x1^2, log(x1) etc. individually, but given the size of my data, this is not practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is suggestion on how to automate the process:

You don't provide any sample data, so I'm going to use `mtcars`:

```
df <- mtcars[, c(1,5:7)];
```

Here, the response is column `1`, and I consider 3 predictor variables in columns `5-7`.

The goal is to automatically build all relevant terms and use those to construct a `formula`, which we then use in `lm`.

1. Build all predictor terms:

   ```
   # All but the first column are predictors
   terms <- sapply(colnames(df)[-1], function(x)
       c(x, sprintf("I(%s^2)", x), sprintf("log(%s)", x)));
   terms;
   #     drat        wt        qsec
   #[1,] "drat"      "wt"      "qsec"
   #[2,] "I(drat^2)" "I(wt^2)" "I(qsec^2)"
   #[3,] "log(drat)" "log(wt)" "log(qsec)"
   ```
2. Construct the formula expression as a string.

   ```
   exprs <- sprintf("%s ~ %s", colnames(df)[1], paste(terms, collapse = "+"));
   exprs;
   [1] "mpg ~ drat+I(drat^2)+log(drat)+wt+I(wt^2)+log(wt)+qsec+I(qsec^2)+log(qsec)"
   ```
3. Run the linear model.

   ```
   model <- lm(as.formula(exprs), data = df);
   ```
4. Re-fit model using all combinations of predictor variables.

   ```
   require(olsrr);
   k <- ols_all_subset(model);
   k;
   #    # A tibble: 511 x 6
   #   Index     N        Predictors `R-Square` `Adj. R-Square` `Mallow's Cp`
   #   <int> <int>             <chr>      <chr>           <chr>         <chr>
   # 1     1     1           log(wt)    0.81015         0.80382       9.73408
   # 2     2     1                wt    0.75283         0.74459      21.12525
   # 3     3     1           I(wt^2)    0.64232         0.63040      43.08976
   # 4     4     1         I(drat^2)    0.46694         0.44917      77.94664
   # 5     5     1              drat    0.46400         0.44613      78.53263
   # 6     6     1         log(drat)    0.45406         0.43587      80.50653
   # 7     7     1         log(qsec)    0.17774         0.15033     135.42760
   # 8     8     1              qsec    0.17530         0.14781     135.91242
   # 9     9     1         I(qsec^2)    0.17005         0.14239     136.95476
   #10    10     2 log(wt) log(qsec)    0.87935         0.87103      -2.02118
   ## ... with 501 more rows
   ```

---

A few comments:

1. This very quickly gets very computationally intensive.
2. The `y ~ .` formula syntax is very concise, but I haven't found a way to include e.g. quadratic terms. On one hand, `y ~ . + (.)^2` works for including all interaction terms; on the other hand, `y ~ . + I(.^2)` does *not* work for quadratic terms. That's why I think building terms manually is the way to go.